# Compiling WebRTC has failed

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, webrtc

I wanted to compile WebRTC for an Android project. Therefore, I followed the steps at https://medium.com/@silvestr1994/webrtc-on-android-part-1-building-b6982aad4b49 .
Every step was fine until I came to the Compiling step (Step-4):

```
gn gen out/Debug --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm"'
```

When I put this into the commandline, then it outputs the following error:

```
ac3l1k@ac3l1k-C:~/Desktop/PROJECT/WebRTC-code/src$ gn gen out/Debug --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm"'
ERROR at //build/config/linux/pkg_config.gni:103:17: Script returned non-zero exit code.
    pkgresult = exec_script(pkg_config_script, args, "value")
                ^----------
Current dir: /home/ac3l1k/Desktop/PROJECT/WebRTC-code/src/out/Debug/
Command: python /home/ac3l1k/Desktop/PROJECT/WebRTC-code/src/build/config/linux/pkg-config.py -s /home/ac3l1k/Desktop/PROJECT/WebRTC-code/src/build/linux/debian_sid_amd64-sysroot -a x64 glib-2.0 gmodule-2.0 gobject-2.0 gthread-2.0
Returned 1.
stderr:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ac3l1k/Desktop/PROJECT/WebRTC-code/src/build/config/linux/pkg-config.py", line 248, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ac3l1k/Desktop/PROJECT/WebRTC-code/src/build/config/linux/pkg-config.py", line 143, in main
    prefix = GetPkgConfigPrefixToStrip(options, args)
  File "/home/ac3l1k/Desktop/PROJECT/WebRTC-code/src/build/config/linux/pkg-config.py", line 82, in GetPkgConfigPrefixToStrip
    "--variable=prefix"] + args, env=os.environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 216, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

See //build/config/linux/BUILD.gn:89:3: whence it was called.
  pkg_config("glib") {
  ^-------------------
See //build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn:218:18: which caused the file to be included.
    configs += [ "//build/config/linux:compiler" ]
                 ^------------------------------
```

Can anybody help ?

Note: I am using Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please visit this article which is quite helpful for webrtc native development as well as compilation of webrtc native stack. [compilation_of_webRtc_Library](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Compile_WebRTC_Library_For_Android)

Answer (score 1):

just lack of pkg-config when calling pkg_config("glib").
`sudo apt install pkg-config`